# What type of fuel is used in helicopters?

Tags: helicopter, fuel, fuel-tanks, jet-fuel

What type of fuel is used in helicopters?

Do they use Aviation Turbine Fuel (jet fuel), which is used widely in commercial airlines?

Also, where would be the fuel tank located in a helicopter?

Comment: Commercial airlines typically use Jet-A/1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It depends on the engine. A piston engine will use avgas (aviation gasoline) or diesel (or Jet-A for availability reasons) depending on whether the engine is a diesel engine (which can burn jet fuel), while a turbine engine will use jet fuel. Essentially whatever the engine is rated to burn.

The fuel tank is somewhere in the fuselage near the center of the rotor. This to avoid the center of gravity shifting with the fuel level.

Comment: A Diesel helicopter? I've never heard of such a thing.

Comment: @Gabe: Looks like some work has been done in that area, though: http://www.wired.com/2010/02/europeans-love-their-diesel-helicopters-are-next/

Comment: How long before we have helicopters parked on off-ramps overnight... (couldn't resist. :)

Comment: wired is hardly a credible source for helicopters! there aren't any certificated diesel helis

Comment: Besides, aviation diesels burn Jet-A anyway.

Comment: That's the main reason for having a diesel in an aircraft.  Diesel fuel doesn't work that well as aviation fuel.  But diesels can run on Jet A, which is widely available and cheaper than the older, 100-octane, leaded avgas.  The latter is getting harder to find and more expensive with each pass year.  Considering the fact that 2014 was SUPPOSED TO be the year they phased out leaded aviation fuel altogether, that's not surprising.